# How to: wordpress job listing and candidates details

Tags: custom-post-types, uploads, query-variable

I am developing a wordpress site (http://new.saffronresourcing.com/candidates/) where candidates who wants to apply for jobs will be able to upload their cv along with their personal details. I already created custom content type for job list which will be used for job listing. It is working fine. Now there is a "apply now" button attached to all job listing. Problem is

When the user clicks apply button, it goes to another page named `uploadcv.php`. Question is when I'm in `uploadcv.php` page, I have no way to find which job listing page user came from. So I need a reference variable which will hold the current page job list ref. number and when user clicks apply now button it will carry out that variable and move to `uploadcv.php` page so I can save the details to the database along with that job reference number.

Is there any idea how to get the current page URL and pass to the next page?

Now as I said earlier candidates will upload their cv, I'm not sure whether how I am gonna add this CV (type .doc, .pdf) into mysql database. Is their any special code to insert the .pdf or .doc file to the database ?

And when the information will be added to the database, I also need to retrieve those details and display in wordpress dashboard so the admin of the site can view which candidates applied for which jobs. So i'm looking for some kind of options panel or candidates lists page where the data will come from database.

So in a nutshell, Please let me know if you guys know how to get the current page URL and pass to next page insert the values from details entry form to database and retrieve the values and display into dashboard, somewhere in dashboard so admin can view the candidates list.

I'm aware there is a plugin exists wp job manager, but I have no clue how to use this plugin, couldn't find a proper documentation. So I decided I will not use this plugin and write code by myself. If you guys know about this plugin, let me know how did you use this for job listing purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the listing is a custom post type so each job listing has a post ID so you can just pass that to your uploadcv.php in your **Apply Now** Button :

```
<a href=".../uploadcv.php?listing_id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">Apply Now</a>
```

and then retrieve that in your uploadcv.php :

```
$listing_ID = (int)$_GET['listing_id'];
```

Now as far as saving the CV in the database, that would be a bad id, when you can simply upload the cv to your server and just save the URL in the database.

Comment: thanks mate, its an good idea, i will apply tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Baininternet, one thing, if I want to pass two variables to another page then how to pass ? one will be post url as you mentioned but i also want to pass the job reference number which is a custom field. can I pass two two variables into <a href= ......>Apply now</a> ?? maybe usiing & operator. what do you think? thnx in advance.